# javascript alert is not returning any value

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I have a particular function that should execute only after I click OK in the alert box
my code is like this.I dont know whether there is 'dialogueresult'in javascript,like that in c#

```
    function showCreds() {
       var y='';
       var result=UpdateCredentials();
       if(result=='1'){y = alert('Creds updated successfully');}
       if(y==true){
         clearFields();
       }
    }
```

Is there any possible way to do this.I also did a test code for this

```
function myfun() {
    var y = alert('test');
    alert(y);
}
```

but the second alert is showing undefined,and if

```
alert(y);
```

is replaced with

```
alert(y.toString())
```

nothing is displaying
also have to work with alert, neither confirm nor prompt

Comment: What would you expect alert to return? Perhaps you are thinking about prompt or confirm?

Comment: You can't alert out an alert. Also the `..` is invalid syntax.

Comment: `alert` has only one button, so there is no need to check for the condition

Comment: like ` function showCreds() {
     var result = UpdateCredentials();
     if (result == '1') {
         y = alert('Creds updated successfully');
         clearFields();
     }
 }`

Comment: Javascript confirm box will return true if the user clicked ok so a simple test would be `var result = confirm("my message for the box"); if(results){ //do something }`

Comment: I dont need to add a confirm box, I need just alert box with single OK button.
What ever it returns doesnt matter, but i need to do further actions according only after the alert

Comment: @Arvin i've added an answer which is, i think what you are after. A simple Javascript alert doesn't return anything but because Javascript is single threaded your additional functionality will run once the OK has been clicked on that alert. Check my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your last comment, the code below would work. Javascript is single threaded so once the alert box has been OKed then `clearFields()` will run

```
function showCreds() {
   var result=UpdateCredentials();
   if(result=='1') {
     alert('Creds updated successfully');
     clearFields();
   }
}
```

Comment: The return value of what? He stated in his last comment that it doesn't matter what the return value is he just wants to run his additional functionality, which in this case is `clearFields()` after the `alert()` which it will.

Comment: Then i dont understand why a alert required , just saying no offence :)..+1 for u

Comment: I think Arvin's question may have been confusing and would imply that he wanted a `prompt` box when infact he just wants to run his functionality after an alert to the user. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `confirm()` instead of `alert()`, it returns `true` or `false` (depending if the user click on "OK" or "Cancel")

[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3rHdQ/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `confirm` instead of `alert`

```
function showCreds() {
       var y='';
       var result=UpdateCredentials();
       if(result=='1'){y = confirm('Creds updated successfully');}
       if(y==true){
         clearFields();
       }
    }
```

Comment: But i need only OK button